# how to delete selected row from datagridview

Tags: database, vb.net, sql-delete

Whenever i run it this exception appears "conversion failed when nvarchar value 'columnvalue' to datatype int." Any idea why? Also is this a permanent way to delete a row? Thanks for the future suggestions!

```
 Dim dataindex As Integer = Me.DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index
    Try
        con = New SqlConnection
        con.ConnectionString = Login.constring
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("DELETE FROM tblmovies where movietitle = @a ", con)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@a", dataindex))
        con.Open()
        If MessageBox.Show("Do you really want to Delete this Record?", "Delete", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning) = DialogResult.Yes Then
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            con.Close()

            Exit Sub
        Else
            con.Close()
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Catch ex As SqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Comment: movietitle would seem more like the name of a movie but you're comparing it to an index derived from the currentrow of your datagridview. You might want to set your parameter to the column value that holds your movietitle on your currentrow or instead pass the primary key of the row (if you have access to it from your currentrow)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim i As Integer = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Index
    DataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(i)
End Sub
```

Comment: delete your record and fill again your gridview

Comment: i dont think there is other way